# Youtube Player Full screen control not working in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube

i used YoutubePlayerFragment for playing videos , but when i click on Full screen control option , the screen rotates to landscape mode and it gives view not found exception.

[image]

```
 **i am using the following logic:**


    Fragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.youtubeplayerview, fragment);
    ft.commit(); 
    YouTubePlayerFragment youtubeFrag = (YouTubePlayerFragment) fragment;
    youtubeFrag.initialize(API_KEY, this);


@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean wasRestored) {
      if (!wasRestored) {

          this.playe=player;
          playe.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
          playe.loadVideo(videoid,starttime);

          }
     }
```

So, please guide me how to achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can do manual configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml for youtube activity, something like this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: This simply removes the problem of not starting video when we click full screen option on youtube player. thanks alot